# How could this C fragment be written more safely?

Tags: c, memory-management, cstring, null-terminated, strdup

I have the following C code fragment and have to identify the error and suggest a way of writing it more safely:

```
char somestring[] = "Send money!\n";
char *copy;

copy = (char *) malloc(strlen(somestring));

strcpy(copy, somestring);
printf(copy);
```

So the error is that strlen ignores the trailing `'\0'` of a string and therefore it is not going to be allocated enough memory for the copy but I'm not sure what they're getting at about writing it more safely?

I could just use `malloc(strlen(somestring)+1))` I assume but I'm thinking there must be a better way than that?

---

**EDIT:** OK, I've accepted an answer, I suspect that the strdup solution would not be expected from us as it's not part of ANSI C.  It seems to be quite a subjective question so I'm not sure if what I've accepted is actually the best.  Thanks anyway for all the answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char   somestring[] = "Send money!\n";
char   *copy;
size_t copysize;

copysize = strlen(somestring)+1;
copy = (char *) malloc(copysize);
if (copy == NULL)
    bail("Oh noes!\n");

strncpy(copy, somestring, copysize);
printf("%s", copy);
```

Noted differences above:

- Result of `malloc()` must be checked!
- Compute and **store** the memory size!
- Use `strncpy()` because `strcpy()` is naughty. In this contrived example it won't hurt, but don't get into the habit of using it.

**EDIT:**

To those thinking I should be using `strdup()`... that only works if you take the very narrowest view of the question. That's not only silly, it's overlooking an even better answer:

```
char somestring[] = "Send money!\n";
char *copy = somestring;
printf(copy);
```

If you're going to be obtuse, at least be good at it.

Comment: +1 for use of strncpy.  That's the source of so many security holes, it's not funny.

Comment: Using strncpy() badly is worse than using strcpy() badly.  If you use strncpy(), you are *NOT* guaranteed null terminated output (this example is OK, but not in general). Also, if you use over-size buffers and sizeof(buffer) for the third parameter to strncpy(), you have a performance mini-disaster on your hands; strncpy() zealously zero-pads the copied data to full length. *YES* to knowing length of source and target strings; if you do that correctly, using strcpy() is safe and safer than blind use of strncpy(). (If it is any help, strncat() is far, far worse than strncpy(); never use it!)

Comment: Jonathan, strlcpy() is much more sane. I use it whenever it's available, and sometime I bring along a version when it's not. Too bad Drepper is such a dork.

Comment: strncpy() will _always_ write N characters, and should be used only when manipulating length-limited not-necessarily-null-terminated arrays-of-char, as for example filenames in old-style Unix directory entries, the application for which it was originally designed.

Comment: -1 for using malloc() to in a string copy when you have strdup().

Answer (score 7):

I can't comment on the responses above, but in addition to checking the
return code and using `strncpy`, you should never do:

```
printf(string)
```

But use:

```
printf("%s", string);
```

ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format_string_attack

Answer (score 6):

```
char somestring[] = "Send money!\n";
char *copy = strdup(something);

if (copy == NULL) {
    // error
}
```

or just put this logic in a separate function **xstrdup**:

```
char * xstrdup(const char *src) 
{
    char *copy = strdup(src);

    if (copy == NULL) {
       abort();
    }

    return copy;
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that strdup() is not a part of ANSI C.

Comment: it should be: if (copy == NULL) {

Comment: If strdup() does not exist for your C library, then you should write it. That means you have a single point where a bug can occur instead of hundreds.

Answer (score 3):

1. strlen + 1, for the \0 terminator
2. malloc may fail; always check malloc return value

Answer (score 3):

Ick... use `strdup()` like everyone else said and write it yourself if you have to. Since you have time to think about this now... check out the [25 Most Dangerous Programming Errors at Mitre](http://www.mitre.org/news/digest/defense_intelligence/02_09/errors.html), then consider why the phrase `printf(copy)` should **never** appear in code. That is right up there with `malloc(strlen(str))` in terms of utter badness not to mention the headache of tracking down why it causes lots of grief when copy is something like `"%s%n"`...

Answer (score 1):

I would comment to previous solutions but I do not have enough rep.
Using **strncpy** here is as wrong as using **strcpy**(As there is absolutely no risk of overflow). There is a function called **memcpy** in *< string.h >* and it is meant exactly for this. It is not only significantly faster, but also the correct function to use to copy strings of known length in standard C.

From the accepted answer:

```
char   somestring[] = "Send money!\n";
char   *copy;
size_t copysize;

copysize = strlen(somestring)+1;
copy = (char *) malloc(copysize);
if (copy == NULL)
    bail("Oh noes!\n");

memcpy(copy, somestring, copysize); /* You don't use str* functions for this! */
printf("%s", copy);
```

Comment: -1 for using malloc() to in a string copy when you have strdup(). Don't reinvent the wheel when you have a library function.

Comment: @Aaron As mentioned before, strdup() is not ANSI, it will not exist on all systems.  The point of this answer can be applied when you write your own version of strdup().

Answer (score 1):

Ways to make the code safer (and more correct).

1. Don't make an unnecessary copy.  From the example, there's no apparent requirement that you actually need to copy `somestring`.  You can output it directly.
2. If you have to make a copy of a string, write a function to do it (or use strdup if you have it).  Then you only have to get it right in one place.
3. Whenever possible, initialize the pointer to the copy immediately when you declare it.
4. Remember to allocate space for the null terminator.
5. Remember to check the return value from `malloc`.
6. Remember to free the `malloc`'ed memory.
7. Don't call `printf` with an untrusted format string.  Use `printf("%s", copy)` or `puts(copy)`.
8. Use an object-oriented language with a string class or any language with built-in string support to avoid most of these problems.

Answer (score 1):

to add more to Adrian McCarthy's ways to make safer code,

Use a static code analyzer, they are very good at finding this kind of errors

Answer (score 0):

The best way to write it more safely, if one were to be truly interested in such a thing, would be to write it in Ada.

```
somestring : constant string := "Send money!";
declare
   copy : constant string := somestring;
begin
   put_line (somestring);
end;
```

Same result, so what are the differences?

- The whole thing is done on the stack
  (no pointers). Deallocation is
  automatic and safe.
- Everything is automaticly range-checked so
  there's no chance of buffer-overflow
  exploits
- Both strings are constants,
  so there's no chance of screwing up
  and modifying them.
- It will probably be way *faster* than the C, not only because of the lack of dynamic allocation, but because there isn't that extra scan through the string required by strlen().

Note that in Ada "string" is not some special dynamic construct. It's the built-in array of characters. However, Ada arrays can be sized at declaration by the array you assign into them.

Answer (score -2):

The safer way would be to use `strncpy` instead of `strcpy`. That function takes a third argument: the length of the string to copy. This solution doesn't stretch beyond ANSI C, so this will work under all environments (whereas other methods may only work under POSIX-compliant systems).

```
char somestring[] = "Send money!\n";
char *copy;

copy = (char *) malloc(strlen(somestring));

strncpy(copy, somestring, strlen(somestring));
printf(copy);
```

Comment: +1 for strncpy; more than anything else, that makes this code safer.  At least in the malloc failure case, you'll segfault; strcpy() allows for insane security holes that are HARD to find.

Comment: @McWafflestix: no, in this case, the strncpy() is misused and the result is a mess.  As Aaron Digulla points out, the call to strncpy() needs the length 'strlen(somestring)+1'; as it is written, the copy is guaranteed not to be null terminated.  The printf() is dangerous in general - using a random string as the format to printf() is bad (puts() is probably the nearest to sane choice here).  (Imagine "Send 20% extra money!" instead!)